# Find the sum of all primes less than $75$ that can be factors of $n^2-3$ such that $n≥2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Find the sum of all prime numbers less than $75$ that can be factors of $n^2-3$ such that $n≥2$.

On trying small values of $n$, I found that $2,3,11,13,7,19,67,43,31$ can be prime factors of $n^2-3$ but I'm not sure that these are the only answers.

Comment: I think the point here is to use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: $n^2 - 3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$   means $n^2 \equiv 3 \pmod p,$  which has a simple expression using Legendre symbol